SwiftUI nested scroll view, unable to scroll vertically if horizontal content is scrolling
I am trying to implement nested scroll views in SwiftUI. Consider the following minimal example:
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack {
                ForEach(Array(1...7), id: \.self) { section in
                    ScrollView(.horizontal) {
                        HStack {
                            ForEach(Array(1...10), id: \.self) { section in
                                Rectangle()
                                    .fill(.blue)
                                    .frame(width: 100.0, height: 150.0)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

It seems to work okay however I have noticed that if any of the horizontal scroll views are scrolling then the vertical scroll locks ups. This makes it very difficult to scroll the content naturally. How can I fix this?
